# How to add a namespace by default when creating a new class in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

In visual studio on windows, if I `right click > add new class` It will generate a class with a namespace that is generated based on the folder structure.  On Mac however it just spits out:

```
using System;
public class NewClass
{
    public NewClass()
    {
    }
}
```

How can I get the namespace to generate on Mac?

Comment: Hello, the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/mac/create-new-projects?view=vsmac-2019) describes how to create a class and add a namespace.

Comment: Hello.  That's not quite what I was looking for.  I'm looking for a setting to have visual studio on mac generate a namespace by default when adding a class via the right click menu.  I do know how to create a class / add a namespace manually :)